# Trying to minimize code to find sum of sub_arrays of a numpy array

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, sum

I have a Numpy array of the following form:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,4,2]]
```

I want to sum all the sublists in the following form:

```
b = [6,15,9]
```

I have the following code that does it:

```
ss = numpy.zeros(shape = [])
for item in a:
    print item
    s = item.sum()
    print s
    b = np.append(ss,s)
```

Here is the result: b = [6,15,9]

Can I do it without this explicit for loop? As in is/are there a numpy function(s) that can make my life easy? This is because the array a is pretty big ~ 10^6 entries.

Comment: Are the sub_arrays of the same length?  If so then `np.array(a)` is a 2d array, and you can sum over `axis=1`.  Otherwise some sort of loop is required, with a list comprehension being the most compact: `[sum(x) for x in [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,4,2]]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ss = a.sum(1)
```

This will do if `a` is a numpy array. If it is a list of numpy arrays or a list-of-lists you want to use:

```
ss = numpy.sum(a, 1)
```

Thanks @DSM for improvement.

Comment: If `a` is an `ndarray`, you could also use the method rather than the function, i.e. `a.sum(1)`.  `numpy.sum(a, 1)` will actually work even if `a` is a list-of-lists.

Comment: @Nabla thanks for your answer. Btw, why use 1 inside the paranthesis in ss = a.sum(1) ?

Comment: @AbhinavKumar The number defines the axis of the two-dimensional array along which is to be summed, see the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) for details.